# Bash/shell error running perl -e 'use [module]': Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1

Tags: perl, bash, shell

I'm writing a shell script that before running needs to check that system Perl updates haven't broken the Perl scripts being glued together.  I keep getting what looks like a parsing error.  To reproduce this on the command line:

```
$ module='Scalar::Util'; check="perl -e 'use $module' 2>&1"; check_status=`$check`; echo $check
Can't find string terminator "'" anywhere before EOF at -e line 1.
perl -e 'use Scalar::Util' 2>&1
```

Anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Handling arguments with spaces in them like that is tricky at best; try to avoid doing so.

You should also use more vertical space; 'one-liners' is a derogatory term, not a term of approval.

You have:

```
module='Scalar::Util'
check="perl -e 'use $module' 2>&1"
check_status=`$check`
echo $check
```

The trouble is that when the shell processes:

```
`$check`
```

it splits the string at word boundaries, yielding arguments:

```
perl
-e
'use
Scalar::Util'
2>&1
```

Note that the I/O redirection is treated as an argument!  To avoid the problem, in this context, you can use:

```
module='Scalar::Util'
check="perl -e 'use $module' 2>&1"
check_status=`eval $check`
echo $check
```

The `eval` forces the shell to reparse the line, getting no errors.

Be careful; simply using `eval` is not always the solution to these woes.  In particular, if you have backslashes, dollars or backticks around (or more quotes), then `eval` can simply compound the problems.

One way of checking whether a module exists in Perl is:

```
perl -M$module -e "print $module::VERSION . '\n'"
```

That gives the module's version number (and complicates the string).  You can also simply do:

```
perl -M$module -e exit
```

which will exit with status 0 if the module is loaded and spew forth errors etc if it is not.

```
$  perl -MSalar::Util -e exit
Can't locate Salar/Util.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /Users/jleffler/Perl/v5.14.1-64/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.1/darwin-2level /Users/jleffler/Perl/v5.14.1-64/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.1 /Users/jleffler/Perl/v5.14.1-64/lib/perl5/5.14.1/darwin-2level /Users/jleffler/Perl/v5.14.1-64/lib/perl5/5.14.1 .).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
$ echo $?
2
$
```

Comment: Perfect.  Works like a charm.  Thanks!  I agree with you about one-liners.  In my script the code is vertically spaced but in shell I packed it into a one-liner so I could do a lot of repetitive trial-and-error using the up arrow.  I should have used separate lines to make it more readable in the question example.

Comment: Please don't suggest that people use eval -- it's an easy way to generate security holes if used carelessly. Bash has arrays: `check=( perl -e "use $module" )`, dereferenceable as `"${check[@]}"` (the quotes are important, by the way)... though why it would be desirable to encapsulate commands in arrays _or_ strings rather than shell functions I'm very much unclear of.

Comment: btw, `perl -M$module -e exit` can be reduced to `perl -M$module -e1`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the shell is doing, but piping `$check` into `sh` seems to work:

```
module='Scalar::Util'; check="perl -e 'use $module' 2>&1";echo $check |sh
```

However, it would be far less clunky to use something like [`Module::Load::Conditional`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Module/Load/Conditional.html) to do this.  You could also use [`pminst`](http://search.cpan.org/~mlfisher/pmtools_1.00.orig/pminst).

Comment: I accepted Jonathan Leffler's answer only because I read it first and it explained exactly what shell was doing to my command string, but I gave your response a +1 because I didn't know about Module::Load::Conditional and pminst and they look useful.  Thanks much.

Comment: BTW, I'll consider Module::Load::Conditional as I'd be able to tailor the check_status output.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if you put commands in a variable, the shell only parses the line once (i.e. when it expends the variable) and so will not handle it when the command itself contains shell special characters. In your case the shell stuff are the `'` and the `2>&1`. This is why bash is giving you the error. Even if you remove the `'`s by using `-m$module` you will still get errors about the `2>&1`

So as the above answers say, you need to use `eval` or invoke a sub shell (`bash` or `sh`) to force the variable to be parsed.

If all you are doing is testing that perl will compile the required module is this good enough?

```
module='Scalar::Util'
perl -m$module
ok=$?
```

Here `ok` will be `0` if everything is cool, or non-0 if there was some kind of error. May not be appropriate if you real problem is a lot more complicated than the posted example.

Comment: Thanks for expounding on the one-time parsing problem.  I had thought about using $? but I wasn't sure about perl return codes and was too lazy to read through the entire perlrun manpage, I also wanted to capture the error text.  By the way, I tried your example but the console hangs on the 'perl -m$module'.  Perhaps you meant something like: perl -m$module -e 'print' ?  That seems to do what you intended. +1 for the useful info.

Answer (score 0):

The only safe way to do this in bash is to use an array. This will properly maintain arguments with whitespace.

```bsh
module='Scalar::Util' 
check=(perl -e "use $module")
check_status=$("${check[@]}" 2&>1)   # must use quotes here
status=$?
echo "$status: $check"
```

Note that the stderr/stdout redirection cannot be part of the command array, you have to specify it as part of the command otherwise it's just another string parameter to the perl command.